# MobileFirst 8 Security issue in Web SDK

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have notice a security breach when implementing/testing the authentication module with MFP 8.0.

We are building a MobileFirst 8 web-based app using MFP Web SDK and we implemented the security check as per the credentials validation security check:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/credentials-validation/

In the client side, after a user is authenticated, we found out that MFP Web SDK is using LocalStorage to save the following entries :

com.mfp.browser.uniqueid, com.sample.pincodeweb.com.mfp.oauth.application.data and com.sample.pincodeweb.com.mfp.oauth.clientid

The problem is when we took the clientid key/value pair from an authenticated user's browser and inserted them in a whole new different browser, unfortunately we found out that the user is being fully authorized and authenticated in the new browser even though we didn't provide any user credentials nor redirected to login.

We have tried it on the PinCode sample:
https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PinCodeWeb/tree/release80

Even the user authentication share the same problem.